# SQL Query and filtering data

Tags: sql, sqlite, greatest-n-per-group, timezonedb

I am using a Time Zone database (https://timezonedb.com/download) and I'm struggling with a SQL query.

The validity of a time zone is depends on time_start field in the database. This is important to get the correct time_start.

**Below are the data**

```
zone_id|zone_name          |time_start
391    |America/Los_Angeles|2147397247
391    |America/Los_Angeles|1425808800
391    |America/Los_Angeles|2140678800
391    |America/Los_Angeles|9972000

392    |America/Metlakatla |2147397247
392    |America/Metlakatla |436352400
392    |America/Metlakatla |9972000

393    |America/Anchorage  |2147397247
393    |America/Anchorage  |2140682400
393    |America/Anchorage  |2120122800
393    |America/Anchorage  |1425812400
393    |America/Anchorage  |9979200
```

The example below shows how to query the time zone information using zone name `America/Los_Angeles`.

```
SELECT * FROM timezone 
WHERE time_start < strftime('%s', 'now')
AND zone_name='America/Los_Angeles'
ORDER BY time_start DESC LIMIT 1;
```

This query returns

```
391|America/Los_Angeles|1425808800
```

I'd like to to do the same thing but for all zone_id with one SQL Query.

**The expected results**

```
391|America/Los_Angeles|1425808800
392|America/Metlakatla |436352400
393|America/Anchorage  |1425812400
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/556d28/2/0)

Comment: This is a [tag:greatest-n-per-group] problem (where the `n` is 1).

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse I didn't know there was a name for that. Thanks for sharing :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are looking for something like this:

```
select tz.zone_id
     , tz.zone_name
     , max(tz.time_start)
from timezone tz 
where tz.time_start < strftime('%s', 'now')
group by tz.zone_id
       , tz.zone_name
order by tz.zone_id;
```

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/556d28/14)

Comment: You are my hero :) No really I was very close, just needed to use the max function. Thank you very much anyway. You've made my day :)